# Segmentation fault on cudaMalloc or cudaMemcpy

Tags: c++, cuda, segmentation-fault

New to CUDA programming and extremely confused as to why I am getting the segfault in the following code:

```
  #include <cuda.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdint.h>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <sstream>
  #include <string>

  using namespace std;

  typedef struct password_t{
      char word[56];
      size_t length;
  } password;

  typedef struct libEntry_t{
      uint8_t digest[16];
      password pwd;
  } libEntry;

  // Generates a library of passwords and their corresponding MD5 hashes
  //
  // Params:
  //    numPwds - the number of passwords for which to generate hashes
  //    pwds    - the list of passwords to hash
  //    library - the array in which to store the unhashed/hashed password library
  __global__ void generateLibraryKernel(int numPwds, password* pwds, libEntry* library)
  {
      // __device__ void cuda_md5(const password *pwd, uint8_t *digest) {
      int index = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
      uint8_t hashed[16];

      if (index < numPwds) {
        cuda_md5(&pwds[index], hashed);
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
          library[index].digest[j] = hashed[j];
        }
        library[index].pwd = pwds[index];
      }
  }

  int crack_password (uint8_t* classified)
  {
      int count = 10;
      unsigned int mem_size = sizeof(password) * count;
      password *h_pwds = (password*) malloc(mem_size);

      ifstream inFile("passwords.txt");
      if (!inFile) {
        cerr << "File passwords.txt not found." << endl;
        return -1;
      }

      string line;
      int i;
      while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        if (line.empty()) continue;
        memcpy(h_pwds[i].word,line.c_str(),line.size());
        h_pwds[i].length = line.size();
        cout << "Password: " << h_pwds[i].word << "\n";
        cout << "Length: " << h_pwds[i].length << "\n";
        i++;
      }

      inFile.close();

      /***** KERNEL CONFIGURATION & MEMORY MANAGEMENT ******/
      password* d_pwds;
      cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_pwds, mem_size);
      cudaMemcpy( d_pwds, h_pwds, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

      libEntry *h_library = (libEntry*) malloc(sizeof(libEntry) * count);

      libEntry* d_library;
      cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_library, sizeof(libEntry) * count);

      int h_numPwds = i;
      cout << "INT NUMPWDS: " << h_numPwds << "\n";

      int* d_numPwds;
      cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_numPwds, sizeof(int));
      cudaMemcpy( d_numPwds, &h_numPwds, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

      /*unsigned int threads_per_block = 1024;
      dim3  grid(1024, 1, 1);
      dim3  threads(threads_per_block, 1, 1);

      // generateLibraryKernel(int numPwds, password* pwds, libEntry* library)
      generateLibraryKernel<<<grid, threads>>>(d_numPwds[0], d_pwds, d_library);

      cudaMemcpy( h_library, d_library, mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);*/

      return 0;
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      if (argc != 2) {
          fprintf(stderr, "usage: ./prog password\n");
          return 1;
      }

      crack_password((uint8_t*) argv[1]);
      cout << "Hack Password: " << argv[1] << "\n";
      return 0;
  }
```

I have gone through it line by line and I believe it happens on the following lines:

```
      int* d_numPwds;
      cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_numPwds, sizeof(int));
      cudaMemcpy( d_numPwds, &h_numPwds, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

When I comment `cudaMemcpy` above, I at least get the `cout` output on my terminal. Note that I have not gotten to the kernel execution part yet, I am just focusing on the memory allocation before I can actually execute and debug the kernel. Any help will be appreciated!

How I have been checking for return status:

```
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(call) do {                                      \
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL_NO_SYNC(call);                                         \
  cudaError err = cudaThreadSynchronize();                              \
  if( cudaSuccess != err) {                                             \
     fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",      \
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );        \
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                \
     } } while (0)
```

EDIT: The error still occurs after I took care of the int memcpy and malloc, apparently I didn't have to alloc or cpy it. Could've just passed it over. So, the error is due to the following lines, and I am not sure which one or why?

```
password* d_pwds;
cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_pwds, mem_size);
cudaMemcpy( d_pwds, h_pwds, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

libEntry *h_library = (libEntry*) malloc(sizeof(libEntry) * count);

libEntry* d_library;
cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_library, sizeof(libEntry) * count);
```

EDIT2: I cleaned up everything and still can't figure it out. By having `CUDA_SAFE_CALL` on the following line `CUDA_SAFE_CALL( cudaMalloc((void**) &d_pwds, pwds_size));` I get segmentation fault even when every other memory allocation command is commented out.

Comment: Try to check the return status of the CUDA calls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api

Comment: @terence hill I have been actually doing that, but I don't get an output instead just segfault. I jave added above the code I was using for checking the status.

Comment: It is almost certainly going to be because you have a buffer overflow the code which loads from file to memory. You make no effort to ensure that no more than `count` lines are read from file. I don't think this has anything to do with CUDA, per se.

Comment: @talonmies Can you please tell me how it can be fixed? Because I have increased `count` to 100 and also my file has only 9 passwords (lines). How is it overflowing?

Comment: Also, if I comment out all the `cudaMemcpy` and `cudaMalloc` lines, the code works. Passwords are nicely loaded into the struct and I can display them. But of course that is useless until I make the kernel work.

Comment: Thats an easy one: `int i;` is not initialized.

Comment: Which i? It wasn't that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone wondering what went wrong, I was able to fix it. I am not exactly sure what exactly was wrong but I had improper memory allocations at some places and in other cases I didn't even needed to use `cudaMalloc` or `cudaMemcpy`. Also, using [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) for checking errors instead of my own implementation worked. What I have now:

```
/***** KERNEL CONFIGURATION & MEMORY MANAGEMENT ******/
/***** GENERATE HASHED PASSWORD LIBRARY FOR COMPARE **/
unsigned int threads_per_block = 1024;
dim3  grid(1024, 1, 1);
dim3  threads(threads_per_block, 1, 1);

password* d_pwds;
ERROR_CHECK( cudaMalloc((void**) &d_pwds, pwds_size));
ERROR_CHECK( cudaMemcpy( d_pwds, h_pwds, pwds_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

libEntry* d_library;
ERROR_CHECK( cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_library, sizeof(libEntry) * count));

// generateLibraryKernel(int numPwds, password* pwds, libEntry* library)
generateLibraryKernel<<<grid, threads>>>(i, d_pwds, d_library);
ERROR_CHECK( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
ERROR_CHECK( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
```

Where `ERROR_CHECK` is defined from the link above.

```
#define ERROR_CHECK(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}
```

I still don't fully understand memory management in CUDA (device and host allocations) but my code works now! Thank you all.